# Customizing Dialogresult MessageBox with user defined MessageBoxButton

Tags: c#, dialogresult

I wan to create a DialogResult MessageBox with my own specified labels on the buttons. I am aware of coding DR MessageBox with YesNo option buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making custom message Box with your own customized buttons and icons and Label that you want to display.
Create Constructor as below.
Add property **DisplayData** to store messageBox Data To Display.

```
    public void CustomMessage(string title, string dataTodisplay, string leftButton, string rightButton, MessageBoxIcon iconSet)
    {
        // Set up some properties.
        this.Font = SystemFonts.MessageBoxFont;
        this.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayData = dataTodisplay;
        // Do some measurements with Graphics.
        SetFormData(dataTodisplay);

        // Set the title, and some Text properties.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) == false)
        {
            this.Text = title;
        }
        // Set the left button, which is optional.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(leftButton) == false)
        {
            this.ButtonOK.Text = leftButton;                 
        }
        Else
        {
          this.AcceptButton = ButtonCancel
          this.ButtonCancel.Visible = False
        }
        // Set the PictureBox and the icon.
        if ((iconSet != null))
        {
            ShowMessageBoxIcon(iconSet);
        }
```

Assign Icons to picturebox here

```
 private void ShowMessageBoxIcon(MessageBoxIcon iconSet)
    {
        switch (iconSet)
        {
            case MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk:
                PictureBoxIconImage.Image =  Bitmap.FromHicon(SystemIcons.Asterisk.Handle);
                break;
            case MessageBoxIcon.Error:
                PictureBoxIconImage.Image = Bitmap.FromHicon(SystemIcons.Error.Handle);
            /*
             * Add remaining icons here
             * 
             */
        }
       }
        this.ButtonCancel.Text = rightButton
      }
```

Comment: I need a code for c# and not VB.NET

Comment: @ShaivyaSharma Find the edits.I have edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own dialog and put buttons. You can assign dialog result values for buttons.

```
this.button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
this.button2.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No;
```